# how to convert chapters to sections?

Tags: chapters

Last time i have this format. Now i want to remove the chapter word and but the chapter title beside the number.

[image]

I use this code to get this but it has no number beside the title. Also, how do I shift the text upwards ? Im not using any IDE so i dont know what arguments go where. thx.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{10pt}
```

[image]

Comment: `\chapter*{Introduction}`

Comment: thanks. that is much simpler that using the code i copied online. but what about the number

Comment: If you want a section, use `\section` and a document class without chapters.

Comment: no i will lose too much of the formatting done

Comment: You don't need an IDE. Just look at the documentation for [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec).  Can you edit your question to include a minimal compilable document that shows what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this? If you prefer to have the title aligned at the left margin, replace `\filcenter` with `\filright`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\thechapter}{1.5ex}{} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{4ex}{12ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to change all `\chapter` to look like `\section` or only one. The `memoir` class covers the `book`, `report` and `article` classes.

It expects the document to be coded like `report` or `book` with `\chapter` divisions, but using the `article` option `\chapter` will be treated like `\section`, `\section` like `\subsection`, etc.

```
\documentclass[article,...]{memoir}
% and so on
\end{document}
```

will cause `and so on` to be treated as though it was an `article`.